# creating your own python code fixer (not debugger, although it could be used for that)

Tags: python, function, overwrite

So I used to always code using hacks like `if type(my_list[0]) == str`, but then I learned of the `isinstance` method, and I got an idea:

**What if I could run my own search and replace function to make my code more efficient and pythonic?**

So I have an idea for a script, and I will describe it to you:

```
def fix_script(find,replace,*args):
    #code goes here
```

What this will do, is search the files in `args` for `find`, and replace it with `replace`...**here is the tricky part**...I want to be able to do this in a somewhat algebraic replacing way. Here is an example:

```
find = 'type({x}) == {y}:'
replace == 'isinstance({x},{y}):'
import os
directory = "Users/name/..."
files = os.listdir(directory)
fix_script(find,replace,files[0],files[1],files[2])
```

so lets say `files[0]` looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
tester = df.number[0]
if type(tester) == str:
    #do something
elif type(tester) == int:
    #do something
elif type(tester) == float:
    #do something
else:
    print "invalid type"
```

after the function runs, that file would have been overwritten to look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
tester = df.number[0]
if isinstance(tester,str):
    #do something
elif isinstance(tester,int):
    #do something
elif isinstance(tester,float):
    #do something
else:
    print "invalid type"
```

So there are two parts to making this possible:

1. To be able to write a function that will be able to search
   algebraically
2. To have that function be able to take a python script, and
   over-write parts of it

Any ideas if this is possible, and if so, how I can accomplish it?

Note: I need a function that can do this with different finds and replaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution here, is to use regexes. What this function does is pretty simple: you add a path to it, and it will scan that path for python files. If found one, open it in both read and write modes, and replaces all the text of `pattern` to `repl`, and then write the changes back to the file.

Script:

```
import os
import re

def fix_pys(path, pattern, repl):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            if ext == '.py':
                with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r+') as py:
                    new_py = re.sub(pattern, repl, py.read())
                    py.seek(0)
                    py.write(new_py)
                    py.truncate()
```

Usage:

```
fix_pys(
    '/Users/me/my_folder',
    r'type\((\w+)\)\s*==\s*(\w+)',
    # r'' -> raw string
    # \( and \) is a necessary escape, because braces means groups in regexes
    # \w+ means more than word character (word characters are: a-z A-Z 0-9 and _)
    # \s* means 0 or more spaces
    r'isinstance(\1, \2)'
    # \1 refers to the content of the first group
    # \2 refers to the content of the second group
)
```

Comment: this seems like a doable answer to solve the example problem, but it is not a function capable of what I asked for. Also, it is very difficult for me to understand/read as a newbie to regex

Comment: @RyanSaxe what this function does is pretty simple: you add a `path` to it, and it will scan that path for python files. If found one, open it in both read and write mode, and replaces all the `type` statements to `isinstance` statements, and then write it to the file. I will explain the regexes, i will my answer. What is exactly the thing you need, and this script doesn't know?

Comment: So I see that this answer works. But the `type` to `isinstance` is not all I want to be able to do. I essentially want to be able to search any python files for a specific line, and replace it with another specific line. So another example would be replacing any line that starts with `for`, but does not have a colon at the end, with the same line with a colon at the end. So it is a very useful function with many updating/fixing/debugging applications

Comment: You can call the same function, but replace the regular expressions with ones that handle your `for` loop replacement, or whatever other fix you want to do.

Comment: @RyanSaxe I created it, so you can change the regexes, and also explained the regexes to you.

Comment: @RyanSaxe for testing create a folder, and put some test python files in it. Create a new python file in the same folder, copy-paste my codem ande replace the `'/Users/me/my_folder'` with `os.getcwd()` when calling my function.

Comment: that's what I did...I put one python file in a folder with like 6 images, and it never changed that file...sorry I mistyped before

Comment: @RyanSaxe fixed my previous comment, added the `os.getcwd()` — which will get your current working directory. It is very important, that the path attribute should be pointing to a folder, not to a file.

Comment: `>>> path
'/Users/ryansaxe/Desktop/peg'` which is a folder with 6 images and 1 python file

Comment: @RyanSaxe I've tested my code now, on a lot of different python files in a lot od different folders and it is working.. I copy-pasted your example code from above

Comment: @RyanSaxe `fix_pys('/Users/ryansaxe/Desktop/peg', r'type\((\w+)\)\s*==\s*(\w+)', r'isinstance(\1, \2)')`

Comment: It is better to use: `os.path.join(<path to directory>, <filename with extension>)`

Comment: wait...nevermind...okay so this works if I use regex as the inputs...I was using my example inputs...is there any way that I could use my example inputs? regex seems to work, but I would rather be able to do this in a very readable manner, which regex is not. is that even possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31884/discussion-between-ryan-saxe-and-peter-varo)